# How to update time every minute in moment-js component in Polymer 2?

Tags: javascript, polymer, momentjs, polymer-2.x

I'm using [moment-js](https://github.com/saeidzebardast/moment-js) component in Polymer 2. The time doesn't update every minute, I've to refresh the page to update the time. How to update time every minute without refreshing the page?
I'm using the following code:

```
<moment-js class="clock title" format="hh:mm A"></moment-js>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Umit pointed out, the [`_updateFormattedDateMoment()`](https://github.com/saeidzebardast/moment-js/blob/1711398/moment-js.html#L203) function from `moment-js` would update the displayed time. This is how you would use it in Polymer 2:

```
class XFoo extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() { return 'x-foo'; }

  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    setInterval(() => this.updateDate(), 1000);
  }

  updateDate() {
    // assumes <moment-js id="clock" ...>
    this.$.clock._updateFormattedDateMoment();
  }
}
customElements.define(XFoo.is, XFoo);
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/RgLNoZ?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the protected `_updateFormattedDateMoment()` function.

In your parent component you can do something like this:

```
created: function() {
    this.timer = setInterval(this.updateDate, 1000);
}

updateDate: function() {
    var moment = this.root.querySelector('.clock');
    moment._updateFormattedDateMoment();
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. The syntax you're using is of Polymer 1. Even after changing it into Polymer 2 it didn't work.